# GLFW link not working correctly with mingw32 in C++ (?)

Tags: c++, linker, glfw

Im trying to compile this example from the `GLFW` webpage:

http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Im using mingw32, and I downloaded the 32-bit windows binaries files from here http://www.glfw.org/download.html.

I put them in the respectives folders:

`glfw3.dll` in `C:\Programming\MinGW32\bin` and a copy in my `main.cpp` folder.

`glfw3dll.a` and `libglfw3.a` in `C:\Programming\MinGW32\lib`

`GLFW folder` with its .h files in `C:\Programming\MinGW32\include`

To compile all I use this: `g++ -lglfw3dll -lopengl32 main.cpp -Wall -o main.exe`

And this are the errors Im getting:

```
D:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Wc7r.o:animation.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
D:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Wc7r.o:animation.cpp:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
D:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Wc7r.o:animation.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
D:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Wc7r.o:animation.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
D:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Wc7r.o:animation.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
D:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Wc7r.o:animation.cpp:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
D:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Wc7r.o:animation.cpp:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
D:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Wc7r.o:animation.cpp:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
C:\Programming\MinGW32\bin/ld.exe: D:\Users\Jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\ccA4Wc7r.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
C:\Programming\MinGW32\bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can see that the linker is someway unable to link with glfw, but why ? and what am I doing worng ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you used to compile is the problem. It should be:

`g++ main.cpp -lglfw3dll -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -Wall -o main.exe`

This is because you first compile main.cpp and then link the libraries to it. The `gdi32` library is also needed when creating OpenGL context.